# Error when trying to update_report() using reportfactory

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am new to the reportfactory package in R. I am trying to set up a report factory to make my rmarkdown files more trackable in my github. I first created a new factory in the directory of my github repo, then I manually moved all my rmarkdown files into the report_source folder inside the directory for this factory. However, when I tried to execute the command update_reports(), I ran into error.

Code and error are listed below:

```r
library(reportfactory)

destination <- file.path(getwd(), "my_reports")
new_factory(destination)

update_reports()

/// compiling report: 'posterior_gravity_2019-08-06'
Error in get0(oNam, envir = ns) : 
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/R/rmarkdown.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the R session, and it successfully rendered the markdown files!

Another thing to make sure is to keep all directories in the Rmd files' code chunks to be consistent with their current locations. It's easy to move these markdown files into the report factory's directory while forgetting to change the directories in the code.